# How do I know the generated trace by verifier is optimal?

Tags: model-checking, uppaal

I'm a beginner of  UPPAAL. I have a question in the verifier part of the software.
I set the option diagnonal trace to fastest. And I check a property, it will generate a fastest trace by verifier.

I was wondering whether this trace is the fastest trace of the model. Or I need to verify it further to check its optimality.
Thank you!